# Results : There is no data to display

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, no-data

```
 SELECT
   *
 FROM 
`fleet-gamma-355414.bikes_data.12_months_data` 
 WHERE
  started_at BETWEEN '2020-06-01'AND '2020-06-01'
 ORDER BY
  started_at;
```

So I was to get the dates that only show from one month (June) and sorted in ascending order, but running the query gave this result.

> There is no data to display.

Here is the SCHEMA

```
:Field name: Type: Mode: Collation: Default: Value: Policy: Tags: Description:
------------------------------------------------------------------------

 ride_id             STRING     NULLABLE            
 rideable_type       STRING     NULLABLE            
 started_at          TIMESTAMP  NULLABLE            
 ended_at            TIMESTAMP  NULLABLE            
 start_station_name  STRING     NULLABLE            
end_station_name     STRING     NULLABLE            
start_lat            FLOAT      NULLABLE            
start_lng            FLOAT      NULLABLE            
end_lat              FLOAT      NULLABLE            
end_lng              FLOAT      NULLABLE            
member_casual        STRING     NULLABLE
```

Sorry, I don't know why the table or the query is like that. I don't know how to edit it
started_at is TIMESTAMP

Comment: have you checked if there is data for that day?

Comment: That means there is not result witihin that date correct? Because I thought I put 2020-06-01 AND 2020-06-30, I instead put 2020-06-01 and 2020-06-01. Now I see data from that specific date.

Comment: Hey how you edit the query to make look like a query and the table, because I don't see that works for me

Comment: i would add hours to the query So tat you have `BETWEEN '2020-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-06-02 00:00:00'`

Comment: As **TIMESTAMP**,  '2020-06-01' is same as '2020-06-01 00:00:00', I think that's why you dont have any result by the between condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Why] There is no data to display.

Because `started_at` is of `timestamp` data type

```
started_at BETWEEN '2020-06-01'AND '2020-06-01'
```

is equivalent to

```
started_at BETWEEN '2020-06-01 00:00:00'AND '2020-06-01 00:00:00'
```

and thus looks like there is no data for that exact second present in your table

> I don't know how to edit it

To resolve this - you should cast `started_at` into `date` data type  - which is done with help of `DATE()` function - so now you really looking for data anywhere within `2020-06-01` date

So, use below

```
 SELECT
   *
 FROM 
`fleet-gamma-355414.bikes_data.12_months_data` 
 WHERE
  DATE(started_at) BETWEEN '2020-06-01'AND '2020-06-01'
 ORDER BY
  started_at;
```

Comment: Some explanation why this would solve OP's question would be nice. And why even use `BETWEEN`?